# How to use Uint8Array, Uint16Array, Uin32Array

Tags: javascript

I recently just started using `webgl`and I am trying to understand the difference between `Uint8Array, Uint16Array, Uin32Array.` and how you would use them. I found some information about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array but can anyone tell me the difference between them and how you would use them?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Uint***Arrays construct non-typed arrays (commented by [@zfor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2739092/zfor), so, for example, `push` would be `undefined`) with numbers only (still bytes). The difference is that each constructor array has different byte range in memory. `Uint8Array` has 1 byte only, then the limit of a number is `255`. `Uint16Array` is 2 bytes long, then the limit is `65535`. `Uint32Array` is 4 bytes long, so the limit is `4294967295`.

When constructing a Uint*Array you declare the array length as the first argument:

```
var arr = new Uint8Array(1);
```

If you declare a array/buffer/object instead, the constructor still proccess them as a `Uint*Array`.

```
var arr = new Uint8Array([10, 257]);
console.log(arr[0]); // 10
console.log(arr[1]); // 1 (same thing: 257 % 256)
```

Now, see some examples:

```
arr[0] = 256;
console.log(arr[0]); // 0

arr[0] = 255;
console.log(arr[0]); // 255
```

Comment: And typed arrays are not to be confused with regular Arrays. Calling `Array.isArray()` on a typed array will return false. Typed arrays are also not supporting several functions that are present on regular Arrays. e.g.: `push(); pop(); shift(); unshift();` They inherit from `TypedArray.prototype`

Comment: @zfor Thanks. I didn't know about that;